# How to use a Scala Secure Trait in PlayFramework?

Tags: authentication, scala, controller, playframework, traits

I'm trying to build a web application in Scala using [Play Framework](http://scala.playframework.org/). When using Play Framework in Java I can use the [Secure module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/secure) to do authentication for pages that require logins. This is a common problem in many web applications, and I would like to use a general solution for my web application.

I have tried to follow [Mixing controllers using Traits](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/controllers#MixingcontrollersusingTraits) with a Secure trait example, but my trait doesn't even compile, and I don't understand what's wrong.

I have created the trait from the example and saved it on `mysite\app\Secure.scala`:

```
package controllers

import play._
import play.mvc._

trait Secure {
    self:Controller =>

    @Before checkSecurity = {
        session("username") match {
            case Some(username) => renderArgs += "user" -> User(username)
                                   Continue
            case None => Action(Authentication.login)
        }
    }

    def connectedUser = renderArgs("user").get

}
```

Then I use the Secure trait in a simple `mysite\app\MySecretController.scala`:

```
package controllers

import play._
import play.mvc._

object MySecretController extends Controller with Secure {
    def index = <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

But when visiting the page I get Compilation error:

```
The file /app/Secure.scala could not be compiled. Error raised is : expected 
start of definition
```

on this line:

```
@Before ↓checkSecurity = {
```

I also created a simple `mysite/app/User` class:

```
package controllers

class User (name: String){

}
```

Any suggestion on how I can solve this?

---

**UPDATE**

After adding `def` as suggested by Felipe. I get another error `not found: value User` on:

```
case Some(username) => renderArgs += "user" -> ↓User(username)
```

Comment: Where does this code come from? both of the links provided above are dead and I have not found any documentation on the Security module in Play for Scala (I have only found the one for Java).  Note: I am using Play 2.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use keyword def before defining an method.

```
@Before def checkSecurity = {
```

should fix this.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That fixed that error but I got another about `value User`. I created a class `User` but I'm not sure how to do it and it doesn't work. Any suggestions? See my update.

Comment: it's possible you dont have the class User? Or maybe you aren't declaring it a case class, thus you dont have the User.apply() method to your User object companion that you are trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the 'not found: value User' error because its definition is not found. You need to make sure you import the package. Just do:

```
import models._
```

after

```
import play.mvc._
```

To import all models.